# Google Sheets removing leading spaces query results

Tags: google-sheets

My sheet is pulling data from another sheet with:

```
=QUERY('WHERE TO SEND STUDENTS'!A:D, "select B,C,D where A<>'' order by D",1)
```

Some of the contents of D has a leading space which causes it to be at the top of the column. Is there a way to remove this leading space and then sort the column D?

Answer (score 3):

I concede this in the category "Quick & Dirty", but it does the job:

```
=arrayformula( query( if( {0,0,0,1}, TRIM(A:D), A:D), "select Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 <> '' order by Col4", 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to [`trim`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) only column D and combine columns with [`array { }`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en):

`=arrayformula( query( { A:C, TRIM(D:D) }, 
"select Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 <> '' order by Col4", 1 ) )`

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need the if statement, this will do it:

```
=arrayformula(query(TRIM('WHERE TO SEND STUDENTS'!A:D),"select Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 <> '' order by Col4", 1 ) )
```

Comment: That trims every cell though. The OP just wanted to trim column D. But yeah, same difference.